# Clipped SVG path rendering issue in Chrome only when stroke width uses 2px to render

Tags: google-chrome, svg, html-rendering

**Context:**

I am rendering a line chart with a curved path.
The path extends beyond the clipped rect mask / viewbox as I had to animate a zooming effect to a smaller range on the x axis. As such the path is quite large.

**Issue:**

The "zoomed in" path renders with a broken stroke (see [image B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQm5n.png)).

Issue only happens when:

- in Chrome, Mac.
- more than 2 pixels required to render the path (if the stroke is thin enough requiring only one pixel to render the stroke appears fine - (see [image A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlC1e.png)) I was able to find this out when moving the window from my low resolution monitor over to my retina display. You can also notice the issue when zooming into the path.
- When the path is large AND "scaled in / only showing a small section within the viewbox". If some of the plots beyond the viewbox area are removed then the path renders correctly.

Other browsers tested: Safari, Firefox. (Mac) These browsers render the path correctly.

[image: image A]

[image: image B]

Has anyone come across this issue and know of any fixes?

I have tried, using a thin stroke and adding drop-shadow filter which helps on low res screens but still breaks on zoom or some monitors with different resolution settings. Shadow only does not work as it requires a stroke to apply the effect.

Here is the codepen:
https://codepen.io/althea16/pen/yLxLRBP

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 536 383" width="536" height="383"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="wrapper" transform="translate(40,20)">
        <g class="axis x" transform="translate(0,343)" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif"
            text-anchor="middle">
            <path class="domain text-divider" stroke="currentColor" d="M0,6V0H436.00848388671875V6"></path>
            <g class="tick text-secondary" opacity="1" transform="translate(22, 0)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" y2="6" class="hidden"></line><text fill="currentColor" y="9"
                    dy="0.71em">08:45</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick text-secondary" opacity="1" transform="translate(133, 0)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" y2="6" class="hidden"></line><text fill="currentColor" y="9" dy="0.71em">09
                    AM</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick text-secondary" opacity="1" transform="translate(244, 0)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" y2="6" class="hidden"></line><text fill="currentColor" y="9"
                    dy="0.71em">09:15</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick text-secondary" opacity="1" transform="translate(355, 0)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" y2="6" class="hidden"></line><text fill="currentColor" y="9"
                    dy="0.71em">09:30</text>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g class="axis y" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="end">
            <path class="domain text-divider" stroke="currentColor" d="M-6,343.9985656738281H0V0H-6"></path>
            <g class="tick text-secondary" opacity="1" transform="translate(0, 330)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6" class="hidden"></line><text fill="currentColor" x="-9"
                    dy="0.32em">15.1</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick text-secondary" opacity="1" transform="translate(0, 283)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6" class="hidden"></line><text fill="currentColor" x="-9"
                    dy="0.32em">15.2</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick text-secondary" opacity="1" transform="translate(0, 237)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6" class="hidden"></line><text fill="currentColor" x="-9"
                    dy="0.32em">15.3</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick text-secondary" opacity="1" transform="translate(0, 191)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6" class="hidden"></line><text fill="currentColor" x="-9"
                    dy="0.32em">15.4</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick text-secondary" opacity="1" transform="translate(0, 145)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6" class="hidden"></line><text fill="currentColor" x="-9"
                    dy="0.32em">15.5</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick text-secondary" opacity="1" transform="translate(0, 98)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6" class="hidden"></line><text fill="currentColor" x="-9"
                    dy="0.32em">15.6</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick text-secondary" opacity="1" transform="translate(0, 52)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6" class="hidden"></line><text fill="currentColor" x="-9"
                    dy="0.32em">15.7</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick text-secondary" opacity="1" transform="translate(0, 6)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6" class="hidden"></line><text fill="currentColor" x="-9"
                    dy="0.32em">15.8</text>
            </g>
        </g>
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip">
                <rect width="440" height="345" transform="translate(0, -1)"></rect>
            </clipPath>
        
        </defs>
       
        <g class="lines" stroke="red" stroke-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-width="2" clip-path="url(#clip)">
            <path
                d="M-3877882,7311C-3874338,7311,-3870794,7311,-3867250,7311C-3863706,7311,-3860162,7311,-3856618,7311C-3853074,7311,-3849530,7311,-3845986,7311C-3842442,7311,-3838898,7311,-3835354,7311C-3831810,7311,-3828266,7311,-3824722,7311C-3821178,7311,-3817634,7311,-3814090,7311C-3810546,7311,-3807002,7311,-3803458,7311C-3799914,7311,-3796370,7311,-3792826,7311C-3789281.9999999995,7311,-3785737.9999999995,7311,-3782193.9999999995,7311C-3778649.9999999995,7311,-3775105.9999999995,7311,-3771561.9999999995,7311C-3768017.9999999995,7311,-3764473.9999999995,7311,-3760929.9999999995,7311C-3757385.9999999995,7311,-3753841.9999999995,7311,-3750297.9999999995,7311C-3746753.9999999995,7311,-3743209.9999999995,7311,-3739666,7311C-3736122,7311,-3732578,7311,-3729034,7311C-3725490,7311,-3721946,7311,-3718402,7311C-3714858,7311,-3711314,7311,-3707770,7311C-3704226,7311,-3700682,7311,-3697138,7311C-3693594,7311,-3690050,7311,-3686506,7311C-3682962,7311,-3679418,7311,-3675874,7311C-3672330,7311,-3668786,7311,-3665242,7311C-3661698,7311,-3658154,7311,-3654610,7311C-3651066,7311,-3647522,7311,-3643978,7311C-3640434,7311,-3636890,7311,-3633346,7311C-3629802,7311,-3626258,7311,-3622714,7311C-3619170,7311,-3615626,7311,-3612082,7311C-3608538,7311,-3604994,7311,-3601450,7311C-3597906,7311,-3594362,7311,-3590818,7311C-3587274,7311,-3583730,7311,-3580186,7311C-3576642,7311,-3573098,7311,-3569554,7311C-3566010,7311,-3562466,7311,-3558922,7311C-3555378,7311,-3551834,7311,-3548290,7311C-3544746,7311,-3541202,7311,-3537657.9999999995,7311C-3534113.9999999995,7311,-3530569.9999999995,7311,-3527025.9999999995,7311C-3523481.9999999995,7311,-3519937.9999999995,7311,-3516393.9999999995,7311C-3512849.9999999995,7311,-3509305.9999999995,7311,-3505761.9999999995,7311C-3502217.9999999995,7311,-3498673.9999999995,7311,-3495130,7311C-3491586,7311,-3488042,7311,-3484498,7311C-3480954,7311,-3477410,7311,-3473866,7311C-3470322,7311,-3466778,7311,-3463234,7311C-3459690,7311,-3456146,7311,-3452602,7311C-3449058,7311,-3445514,7311,-3441970,7311C-3438426,7311,-3434882,7311,-3431338,7311C-3427794,7311,-3424250,7311,-3420706,7311C-3417162,7311,-3413618,7311,-3410074,7311C-3406530,7311,-3402986,7311,-3399442,7311C-3395898,7311,-3392354,7311,-3388810,7311C-3385266,7311,-3381722,7311,-3378178,7311C-3374634,7311,-3371090,7311,-3367546,7311C-3364002,7311,-3360458,7311,-3356914,7311C-3353370,7311,-3349826,7311,-3346282,7311C-3342738,7311,-3339194,7311,-3335650,7311C-3332106,7311,-3328562,7311,-3325018,7311C-3321474,7311,-3317930,7311,-3314386,7311C-3310842,7311,-3307298,7311,-3303754,7311C-3300210,7311,-3296666,7311,-3293122,7311C-3289578,7311,-3286033.9999999995,7311,-3282489.9999999995,7311C-3278945.9999999995,7311,-3275401.9999999995,7311,-3271857.9999999995,7311C-3268313.9999999995,7311,-3264769.9999999995,7311,-3261225.9999999995,7311C-3257681.9999999995,7311,-3254137.9999999995,7311,-3250593.9999999995,7311C-3247049.9999999995,7311,-3243505.9999999995,7311,-3239961.9999999995,7311C-3236417.9999999995,7311,-3232873.9999999995,7311,-3229329.9999999995,7311C-3225785.9999999995,7311,-3222241.9999999995,7311,-3218698,7311C-3215154,7311,-3211610,7311,-3208066,7311C-3204522,7311,-3200978,7311,-3197434,7311C-3193890,7311,-3190346,7311,-3186802,7311C-3183258,7311,-3179714,7311,-3176170,7311C-3172626,7311,-3169082,7311,-3165538,7311C-3161994,7311,-3158450,7311,-3154906,7311C-3151362,7311,-3147818,7311,-3144274,7311C-3140730,7311,-3137186,7311,-3133642,7311C-3130098,7311,-3126554,7311,-3123010,7311C-3119466,7311,-3115922,7311,-3112378,7311C-3108834,7311,-3105290,7311,-3101746,7311C-3098202,7311,-3094658,7311,-3091114,7311C-3087570,7311,-3084026,7311,-3080482,7311C-3076938,7311,-3073394,7311,-3069850,7311C-3066306,7311,-3062762,7311,-3059218,7311C-3055674,7311,-3052130,7311,-3048586,7311C-3045042,7311,-3041498,7311,-3037954,7311C-3034410,7311,-3030866,7311,-3027322,7311C-3023778,7311,-3020234,7311,-3016690,7311C-3013146,7311,-3009602,7311,-3006058,7311C-3002514,7311,-2998970,7311,-2995426,7311C-2991882,7311,-2988338,7311,-2984794,7311C-2981250,7311,-2977706,7311,-2974162,7311C-2970618,7311,-2967074,7311,-2963530,7311C-2959986,7311,-2956442,7311,-2952898,7311C-2949354,7311,-2945810,7311,-2942266,7311C-2938722,7311,-2935178,7311,-2931634,7311C-2928090,7311,-2924546,7311,-2921002,7311C-2917458,7311,-2913914,7311,-2910370,7311C-2906826,7311,-2903282,7311,-2899738,7311C-2896194,7311,-2892650,7311,-2889106,7311C-2885562,7311,-2882018,7311,-2878474,7311C-2874930,7311,-2871386,7311,-2867842,7311C-2864298,7311,-2860754,7311,-2857210,7311C-2853666,7311,-2850122,7311,-2846578,7311C-2843034,7311,-2839490,7311,-2835946,7311C-2832402,7311,-2828858,7311,-2825314,7311C-2821770,7311,-2818226,7311,-2814682,7311C-2811138,7311,-2807594,7311,-2804050,7311C-2800506,7311,-2796962,7311,-2793418,7311C-2789874,7311,-2786330,7311,-2782786,7311C-2779242,7311,-2775698,7311,-2772154,7311C-2768610,7311,-2765066,7311,-2761522,7311C-2757978,7311,-2754434,7311,-2750890,7311C-2747346,7311,-2743802,7311,-2740258,7311C-2736714,7311,-2733170,7311,-2729626,7311C-2726082,7311,-2722538,7311,-2718994,7311C-2715450,7311,-2711906,7311,-2708362,7311C-2704818,7311,-2701274,7311,-2697730,7311C-2694186,7311,-2690642,7311,-2687098,7311C-2683554,7311,-2680010,7311,-2676466,7311C-2672922,7311,-2669378,7311,-2665834,7311C-2662290,7311,-2658746,7311,-2655202,7311C-2651658,7311,-2648114,7311,-2644570,7311C-2641026,7311,-2637482,7311,-2633938,7311C-2630394,7311,-2626850,7311,-2623306,7311C-2619762,7311,-2616218,7311,-2612674,7311C-2609130,7311,-2605586,7311,-2602042,7311C-2598498,7311,-2594954,7311,-2591410,7311C-2587866,7311,-2584322,9332,-2580778,9332C-2577234,9332,-2573690,6012.999999999999,-2570146,5949C-2566602,5885,-2563058,5917,-2559514,5853C-2555970,5789,-2552426,3225,-2548882,3225C-2545338,3225,-2541794,5772,-2538250,5772C-2534706,5772,-2531162,3889.5,-2527618,2989C-2524074,2088.5,-2520530,985.6666666666666,-2516986,369C-2513442,-247.66666666666663,-2509898,-711,-2506354,-711C-2502810,-711,-2499266,263.33333333333337,-2495722,552C-2492178,840.6666666666665,-2488634,708.3333333333333,-2485090,1020.9999999999999C-2481546,1333.6666666666667,-2478002,3737,-2474458,3881C-2470914,4025,-2467370,3987,-2463826,4097C-2460282,4207,-2456738,4277,-2453194,4541C-2449650,4805,-2446106,5681,-2442562,5681C-2439018,5681,-2435474,5474.333333333332,-2431930,5394C-2428386,5313.666666666667,-2424842,5329,-2421298,5199C-2417754,5069,-2414210,3075,-2410666,3075C-2407122,3075,-2403578,3980,-2400034,3980C-2396490,3980,-2392946,3377.833333333333,-2389402,2854C-2385858,2330.1666666666665,-2382314,837,-2378770,837C-2375226,837,-2371682,1414,-2368138,1414C-2364594,1414,-2361050,841,-2357506,841C-2353962,841,-2350418,1826.8333333333335,-2346874,2619C-2343330,3411.1666666666665,-2339786,4864.833333333333,-2336242,5594C-2332698,6323.166666666666,-2329154,6994,-2325610,6994C-2322066,6994,-2318522,5326.166666666667,-2314978,4744C-2311434,4161.833333333333,-2307890,3800.166666666666,-2304346,3500.9999999999995C-2300802,3201.833333333333,-2297258,3317,-2293714,2949C-2290170,2581,-2286626,982,-2283082,982C-2279538,982,-2275994,1984,-2272450,1984C-2268906,1984,-2265362,-2244.6666666666665,-2261818,-2944C-2258274,-3643.333333333333,-2254730,-3992.9999999999995,-2251186,-3992.9999999999995C-2247642,-3992.9999999999995,-2244098,-2769,-2240554,-2769C-2237010,-2769,-2233466,-3447,-2229922,-3447C-2226378,-3447,-2222834,-1810,-2219290,-1810C-2215746,-1810,-2212202,-1996.6666666666667,-2208658,-2106C-2205114,-2215.3333333333335,-2201570,-2466,-2198026,-2466C-2194482,-2466,-2190938,1603,-2187394,1603C-2183850,1603,-2180306,1571.6666666666667,-2176762,1509C-2173218,1446.333333333333,-2169674,-1575.6666666666665,-2166130,-2576C-2162586,-3576.333333333333,-2159042,-4493,-2155498,-4493C-2151954,-4493,-2148410,-4178,-2144866,-4178C-2141322,-4178,-2137778,-5005,-2134234,-5005C-2130690,-5005,-2127146,-4076.333333333333,-2123602,-3923C-2120058,-3769.666666666666,-2116514,-3846.333333333333,-2112970,-3693C-2109426,-3539.666666666666,-2105882,-2787.333333333333,-2102338,-2596C-2098794,-2404.6666666666665,-2095250,-2309,-2091706,-2309C-2088162,-2309,-2084617.9999999998,-2321.666666666666,-2081073.9999999998,-2347C-2077529.9999999998,-2372.333333333333,-2073985.9999999998,-4339,-2070441.9999999998,-4339C-2066897.9999999998,-4339,-2063353.9999999998,-3494,-2059809.9999999998,-3494C-2056266,-3494,-2052722,-3680.6666666666665,-2049178,-4006C-2045634,-4331.333333333333,-2042090,-5446,-2038546,-5446C-2035002,-5446,-2031458,-3705.9999999999995,-2027914,-3705.9999999999995C-2024370,-3705.9999999999995,-2020826,-6174,-2017282,-6174C-2013738,-6174,-2010194,-6165,-2006650,-6165C-2003106,-6165,-1999562,-7385.333333333332,-1996018,-7747C-1992474,-8108.666666666666,-1988930,-7942.999999999999,-1985386,-8335C-1981842,-8727,-1978298,-11704,-1974754,-11704C-1971210,-11704,-1967666,-9294,-1964122,-9294C-1960577.9999999998,-9294,-1957033.9999999998,-10520,-1953489.9999999998,-10520C-1949945.9999999998,-10520,-1946401.9999999998,-8857.5,-1942857.9999999998,-8099.999999999999C-1939313.9999999998,-7342.5,-1935769.9999999998,-7154.666666666667,-1932226,-5975C-1928682,-4795.333333333333,-1925138,-1123.3333333333333,-1921594,-1021.9999999999999C-1918050,-920.6666666666665,-1914506,-870,-1910962,-870C-1907418,-870,-1903874,-2114,-1900330,-2114C-1896786,-2114,-1893242,-1568.9999999999998,-1889698,-1568.9999999999998C-1886154,-1568.9999999999998,-1882610,-2135,-1879066,-2135C-1875522,-2135,-1871978,-1491,-1868434,-1491C-1864890,-1491,-1861346,-2678,-1857802,-2678C-1854258,-2678,-1850714,1364,-1847170,1520C-1843626,1676,-1840082,1597.9999999999998,-1836538,1754C-1832993.9999999998,1910,-1829449.9999999998,3352,-1825905.9999999998,3352C-1822361.9999999998,3352,-1818817.9999999998,952,-1815273.9999999998,952C-1811730,952,-1808186,1938.9999999999998,-1804642,1938.9999999999998C-1801098,1938.9999999999998,-1797554,1918.333333333333,-1794010,1876.9999999999998C-1790466,1835.6666666666665,-1786922,1195,-1783378,1195C-1779834,1195,-1776290,1580.9999999999998,-1772746,1580.9999999999998C-1769202,1580.9999999999998,-1765658,1469.6666666666667,-1762114,1247C-1758570,1024.3333333333333,-1755026,164,-1751482,164C-1747938,164,-1744394,185,-1740850,227C-1737306,269,-1733762,2544,-1730218,2544C-1726674,2544,-1723130,1005,-1719586,841C-1716042,677,-1712498,759,-1708954,595C-1705409.9999999998,431,-1701865.9999999998,-1429.8333333333333,-1698321.9999999998,-2012.9999999999998C-1694777.9999999998,-2596.166666666667,-1691233.9999999998,-2904,-1687690,-2904C-1684146,-2904,-1680602,-2566,-1677058,-2566C-1673514,-2566,-1669970,-2832,-1666426,-2832C-1662882,-2832,-1659338,1308,-1655794,1308C-1652250,1308,-1648706,162,-1645162,162C-1641618,162,-1638074,2450,-1634530,2450C-1630986,2450,-1627442,2320.6666666666665,-1623898,2062C-1620354,1803.3333333333335,-1616810,589,-1613266,589C-1609722,589,-1606178,4182,-1602634,4182C-1599090,4182,-1595546,2707,-1592002,2707C-1588458,2707,-1584914,3032.666666666666,-1581369.9999999998,3357.9999999999995C-1577825.9999999998,3683.3333333333335,-1574281.9999999998,4659,-1570737.9999999998,4659C-1567193.9999999998,4659,-1563649.9999999998,1938.333333333333,-1560105.9999999998,1163C-1556561.9999999998,387.66666666666674,-1553017.9999999998,0,-1549474,0C-1545930,0,-1542386,353.33333333333337,-1538842,565C-1535298,776.6666666666666,-1531754,1270,-1528210,1270C-1524666,1270,-1521122,989,-1517578,989C-1514034,989,-1510490,1842,-1506946,1842C-1503402,1842,-1499858,1765.333333333333,-1496314,1612C-1492770,1458.6666666666667,-1489226,663,-1485682,663C-1482138,663,-1478594,714.3333333333334,-1475050,817C-1471506,919.6666666666665,-1467962,1138.5,-1464418,1451C-1460874,1763.5,-1457330,2692,-1453786,2692C-1450242,2692,-1446698,2032.1666666666667,-1443154,1516C-1439610,999.8333333333331,-1436066,-405,-1432522,-405C-1428978,-405,-1425434,-291.3333333333333,-1421890,-180C-1418346,-68.66666666666667,-1414802,196.33333333333331,-1411258,263C-1407714,329.66666666666663,-1404170,296.3333333333333,-1400626,363C-1397082,429.66666666666663,-1393538,730,-1389994,730C-1386450,730,-1382906,264,-1379362,264C-1375818,264,-1372274,2222.333333333333,-1368730,2525C-1365186,2827.666666666666,-1361642,2979,-1358098,2979C-1354554,2979,-1351010,2975,-1347466,2975C-1343922,2975,-1340378,3069.166666666666,-1336834,3147C-1333290,3224.833333333333,-1329746,3331.8333333333335,-1326202,3442C-1322658,3552.166666666666,-1319114,3808,-1315570,3808C-1312026,3808,-1308482,3601.666666666666,-1304938,3419C-1301394,3236.333333333333,-1297850,2712,-1294306,2712C-1290762,2712,-1287218,3307.8333333333335,-1283674,3664C-1280130,4020.166666666666,-1276586,4661,-1273042,4849C-1269498,5037,-1265954,5131,-1262410,5131C-1258866,5131,-1255322,4663.833333333333,-1251778,4529C-1248234,4394.166666666666,-1244690,4460,-1241146,4322C-1237602,4184,-1234058,3361,-1230514,3361C-1226970,3361,-1223426,4312,-1219882,4312C-1216338,4312,-1212794,2624.1666666666665,-1209250,1781C-1205706,937.8333333333333,-1202162,-747,-1198618,-747C-1195074,-747,-1191530,-87,-1187986,-87C-1184442,-87,-1180898,-1254,-1177354,-2568C-1173810,-3882,-1170266,-7970.999999999999,-1166722,-7970.999999999999C-1163178,-7970.999999999999,-1159634,-6260,-1156090,-6260C-1152546,-6260,-1149002,-6949.666666666667,-1145458,-7436.999999999999C-1141914,-7924.333333333332,-1138370,-9184,-1134826,-9184C-1131282,-9184,-1127738,-6041,-1124194,-5835C-1120650,-5629,-1117106,-5526,-1113562,-5526C-1110018,-5526,-1106474,-9113.333333333334,-1102930,-9194C-1099386,-9274.666666666666,-1095842,-9315,-1092298,-9315C-1088754,-9315,-1085210,-6710.333333333332,-1081666,-5971C-1078122,-5231.666666666666,-1074578,-5601.333333333333,-1071034,-4862C-1067490,-4122.666666666667,-1063946,192,-1060402,2893C-1056858,5594,-1053314,11344,-1049770,11344C-1046226,11344,-1042681.9999999999,4802,-1039137.9999999999,4802C-1035593.9999999999,4802,-1032049.9999999999,5863.333333333333,-1028506,6277C-1024962,6690.666666666666,-1021418,6810,-1017874,7284C-1014330,7758,-1010786,9121,-1007242,9121C-1003698,9121,-1000154,8240.833333333334,-996610,7929C-993066,7617.166666666667,-989522,7249.999999999999,-985978,7249.999999999999C-982433.9999999999,7249.999999999999,-978889.9999999999,7864.666666666666,-975345.9999999999,8048C-971801.9999999999,8231.333333333334,-968258,8350,-964714,8350C-961170,8350,-957626,8312,-954082,8304C-950538,8296,-946994,8292,-943450,8292C-939906,8292,-936362,10013.5,-932818,10545C-929274,11076.5,-925730,11481,-922186,11481C-918641.9999999999,11481,-915097.9999999999,10545.666666666666,-911553.9999999999,10080C-908009.9999999999,9614.333333333334,-904466,8967,-900922,8687C-897378,8407,-893834,8483.666666666666,-890290,8267C-886746,8050.333333333332,-883202,7387,-879658,7387C-876114,7387,-872570,7745,-869026,7745C-865482,7745,-861938,6658,-858394,6658C-854849.9999999999,6658,-851305.9999999999,7709,-847761.9999999999,7709C-844218,7709,-840674,7027.666666666667,-837130,6530C-833586,6032.333333333332,-830042,4723,-826498,4723C-822954,4723,-819410,5853,-815866,5853C-812322,5853,-808778,5534,-805234,5534C-801690,5534,-798146,6439,-794602,6439C-791057.9999999999,6439,-787513.9999999999,5455,-783969.9999999999,5455C-780425.9999999999,5455,-776882,5843.333333333333,-773338,5852C-769794,5860.666666666666,-766250,5856.333333333332,-762706,5865C-759162,5873.666666666667,-755618,7130.999999999999,-752074,7130.999999999999C-748530,7130.999999999999,-744986,6067,-741442,6067C-737898,6067,-734354,6487,-730810,6548.999999999999C-727266,6611,-723722,6580,-720178,6642C-716634,6704,-713090,7175.666666666666,-709546,7274.999999999999C-706002,7374.333333333333,-702458,7424,-698914,7424C-695370,7424,-691826,6477,-688282,6477C-684738,6477,-681194,6904.166666666667,-677650,7186C-674106,7467.833333333333,-670562,7513.333333333333,-667018,8167.999999999999C-663474,8822.666666666666,-659930,11566,-656386,11566C-652842,11566,-649298,10835,-645754,10835C-642210,10835,-638666,10849,-635122,10877C-631578,10905,-628034,12500,-624490,12500C-620946,12500,-617402,11245,-613858,11245C-610314,11245,-606770,11675,-603226,11675C-599682,11675,-596138,11283.666666666666,-592594,11219C-589050,11154.333333333332,-585506,11122,-581962,11122C-578418,11122,-574874,11129,-571330,11143C-567786,11157,-564242,11455,-560698,11455C-557154,11455,-553610,10960,-550066,10960C-546522,10960,-542978,11195.166666666666,-539434,11499C-535890,11802.833333333334,-532346,12783,-528802,12783C-525258,12783,-521713.99999999994,12779.999999999998,-518169.99999999994,12779.999999999998C-514626,12779.999999999998,-511082,13028,-507538,13028C-503994,13028,-500450,12991.999999999998,-496906,12958C-493361.99999999994,12924,-489817.99999999994,12913.333333333332,-486274,12824C-482730,12734.666666666666,-479186,12242.333333333332,-475642,12116.999999999998C-472098,11991.666666666666,-468554,12054.333333333332,-465010,11929C-461465.99999999994,11803.666666666664,-457921.99999999994,10960,-454378,10960C-450834,10960,-447290,11323,-443746,11323C-440202,11323,-436658,10822,-433114,10822C-429569.99999999994,10822,-426025.99999999994,10964,-422482,10964C-418938,10964,-415394,10308.166666666664,-411850,9967C-408306,9625.833333333332,-404762,9238.833333333332,-401218,8917C-397673.99999999994,8595.166666666666,-394129.99999999994,8314.333333333334,-390586,8036C-387042,7757.666666666666,-383498,7548.499999999999,-379954,7247C-376410,6945.5,-372866,6757.5,-369322,6227C-365778,5696.5,-362234,4857.5,-358690,4063.9999999999995C-355146,3270.5,-351602,1466,-348058,1466C-344514,1466,-340970,1881,-337426,1881C-333882,1881,-330338,1843,-326794,1843C-323250,1843,-319706,1950.9999999999998,-316162,2167C-312618,2383,-309074,3214.9999999999995,-305530,3214.9999999999995C-301986,3214.9999999999995,-298442,2718.833333333333,-294898,1935C-291354,1151.1666666666665,-287810,-1488,-284266,-1488C-280722,-1488,-277178,-625,-273634,-625C-270090,-625,-266546,-907.4999999999999,-263002,-1061C-259458,-1214.5,-255914,-1546,-252370,-1546C-248826,-1546,-245282,724,-241738,724C-238194,724,-234650,-965,-231105.99999999997,-965C-227562,-965,-224018,-755.9999999999999,-220474,-755.9999999999999C-216929.99999999997,-755.9999999999999,-213386,-1132,-209842,-1132C-206298,-1132,-202754,-829,-199209.99999999997,-829C-195666,-829,-192122,-2500,-188578,-2500C-185034,-2500,-181490,-202.99999999999997,-177946,-202.99999999999997C-174402,-202.99999999999997,-170858,-1412,-167314,-1813C-163770,-2214,-160226,-2609,-156682,-2609C-153138,-2609,-149594,-2176,-146050,-2176C-142506,-2176,-138962,-2633.5,-135418,-3037C-131874,-3440.5,-128330,-4597,-124785.99999999999,-4597C-121242,-4597,-117697.99999999999,-3547.333333333333,-114154,-3152.9999999999995C-110609.99999999999,-2758.666666666666,-107066,-2231,-103522,-2231C-99978,-2231,-96434,-3814,-92890,-3814C-89346,-3814,-85802,-3429.9999999999995,-82258,-2662C-78714,-1893.9999999999998,-75170,1306,-71626,1314C-68082,1322,-64537.99999999999,1326,-60993.99999999999,1326C-57450,1326,-53906,996,-50362,909.9999999999999C-46818,823.9999999999999,-43274,780.9999999999999,-39730,780.9999999999999C-36186,780.9999999999999,-32641.999999999996,1861,-29098,1861C-25554,1861,-22010,22,-18466,22C-12310.666666666668,22,-6155.333333333332,267,0,267C2.333333333333333,267,4.666666666666666,250,7,250C9.666666666666664,250,12.333333333333334,268.7047619047619,14.999999999999998,276C17.333333333333332,282.3833333333333,19.666666666666668,292,22,292C24.666666666666668,292,27.333333333333332,291,29.999999999999996,291C32.33333333333333,291,34.666666666666664,297.5,37,301C39.333333333333336,304.5,41.666666666666664,306.09722222222223,44,312C46.666666666666664,318.7460317460317,49.333333333333336,341,52,341C54.333333333333336,341,56.66666666666666,322,59,322C61.33333333333333,322,63.66666666666666,324,66,324C68.66666666666667,324,71.33333333333333,308,74,308C76.33333333333333,308,78.66666666666667,344,81,344C83.66666666666666,344,86.33333333333333,295,89,295C91.33333333333333,295,93.66666666666666,299,96,299C98.33333333333333,299,100.66666666666666,297.6666666666667,102.99999999999999,295C105.66666666666667,291.95238095238096,108.33333333333331,272.76190476190476,111,272C113.33333333333331,271.3333333333333,115.66666666666667,271,118,271C120.66666666666666,271,123.33333333333331,271,126,271C128.33333333333334,271,130.66666666666663,251.66666666666663,133,245C135.33333333333334,238.33333333333331,137.66666666666663,231,140,231C142.66666666666666,231,145.33333333333334,289,148,289C150.33333333333334,289,152.66666666666666,262.6666666666667,155,258C157.33333333333334,253.33333333333331,159.66666666666666,255.66666666666666,162,251C164.66666666666663,245.66666666666663,167.33333333333331,230.35238095238094,170,215C172.33333333333334,201.56666666666663,174.66666666666663,179.0722222222222,177,167C179.66666666666666,153.2031746031746,182.33333333333334,143.28571428571428,185,141C187.33333333333331,139,189.66666666666663,140,192,138C194.33333333333334,136,196.66666666666666,121.39722222222221,199,114C201.66666666666666,105.54603174603173,204.33333333333331,102.90793650793651,207,91C209.33333333333334,80.58055555555555,211.66666666666663,55.833333333333336,214,49.99999999999999C216.66666666666663,43.33333333333333,219.33333333333331,40,222,40C224.33333333333331,40,226.66666666666663,97,229,97C231.33333333333334,97,233.66666666666663,61,236,61C238.66666666666666,61,241.33333333333331,80,244,80C246.33333333333331,80,248.66666666666663,64,251,64C253.33333333333331,64,255.66666666666666,74,258,74C260.6666666666667,74,263.3333333333333,69,266,59C268.3333333333333,50.25,270.6666666666667,29.65555555555555,273,20C275.66666666666663,8.965079365079367,278.33333333333326,0,281,0C283.3333333333333,0,285.6666666666667,2.333333333333333,288,5C290.3333333333333,7.666666666666666,292.66666666666663,9.825,295,16C297.6666666666667,23.057142857142857,300.3333333333333,47,303,47C305.3333333333333,47,307.6666666666667,45.666666666666664,310,43C312.33333333333326,40.333333333333336,314.6666666666667,26,317,26C319.6666666666667,26,322.3333333333333,50.476190476190474,325,52C327.3333333333333,53.33333333333333,329.66666666666663,53.099999999999994,332,54C334.66666666666663,55.02857142857142,337.33333333333326,55.34603174603174,340,58C342.3333333333333,60.32222222222222,344.6666666666667,68,347,68C349.33333333333326,68,351.66666666666663,21,354,21C356.6666666666667,21,359.3333333333333,21,362,21C364.3333333333333,21,366.66666666666663,33.5,369,37C371.66666666666663,41,374.33333333333326,43,377,43C379.33333333333326,43,381.6666666666667,20,384,20C386.33333333333326,20,388.6666666666667,29.999999999999996,391,29.999999999999996C393.6666666666667,29.999999999999996,396.3333333333333,20,399,20C401.33333333333326,20,403.6666666666667,32,405.99999999999994,38C408.33333333333326,44,410.66666666666663,56,413,56C415.6666666666667,56,418.3333333333333,49.25714285714285,421,42C423.33333333333326,35.65,425.6666666666667,17,428,17C430.66666666666663,17,433.33333333333326,32,436,32C438.33333333333326,32,440.6666666666667,32,442.99999999999994,32"
                
                style="stroke: rgb(1, 204, 122); fill: none;"></path>
        </g>
       
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: FWIW stroke-effect should be vector-effect

Comment: The path is the problem.  If you take a look at the d attribute you will see at the begining of the path big negative numbers. The same bezier it's repeating over and over. I've deleted the begining of the path where this happens and solved the problem.

Comment: Updated to vector-effect, thank you. Sadly doesn't affect the issue. @enxaneta Those negative path plots are what I was referring to "The path extends beyond the clipped rect mask / viewbox as I had to animate a zooming effect " Sorry if that was unclear. They are indeed the problem but need them to create the zoom effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extreme number of negative plots are definitely the issue although I don't understand why (only an issue in chrome). I needed these negative plots to be able to transition back out into full view.

My workaround was to remove the negative path commands during the transition. Still keep the entire path with negative plots on a seperate data attribute to be used on the next transition, ie zoom out or add new plot. Just had ensure that the d attribute had the negative path commands omitted.

Answer (score 2):

Fascinating problem. I can't see the solution myself but have tried to simplify what you've done into a very simple demo by removing rounded decimals and reducing your paths down to the bare minimum.

It appears that the path off the viewbox is causing the problem, i.e. these two:

```
-3877882,100C-1067490,-4122,-1063946,192,-1060402,2893C-1056858,5594,-1053314,11344,-1049770,11344
```

but it shouldn't render poorly like that. Would be interested to see the solution. Chrome can be so fussy with SVG.

https://codepen.io/PotatoTrade_/pen/eYLYbLe

[image]

Comment: This helps a lot to narrow down the issue. Hopefully someone can help pin point this issue. Maybe the path commands themselves are the issue but for some reason renders fine in other browsers?